# How to I read url parameters in action override aura component?

Tags: aura, button-overrides, lightning-action-override

I have overridden New action on my custom object with Aura component that launches flow.
Standard new action was used with url parameter and input field was filled with default value by framework. Url looks like this:

```
/lightning/o/MyObj__c/new?defaultFieldValues=MyField__c%3D12312312312
```

How do I get any URL parameter in the Aura component that I have overridden action with? `lightning:isUrlAddressible` is returning `null` value of `pageReference` state property.